# Why the Plot[] is plotting the result of expression evaluation always on y axis of coordinate plane?

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization, algebra

I have a code:

```
Plot[-3*x + 2, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}]
```

output:

[image]

and it does not matter what will be variable name instead of `x`, it plots result of the expression on the y axis of coordinate plane.

**Question:** Is this a mathematical convention or Wolfram Mathematica convention to plot expression always on y axis of coordinate plane, or there is something else?

Comment: The plot variable is a dummy variable, i.e., whatever its name it will be on the "x axis" and the function value, whatever its name, will be on the "y axis". If you want to interchange these look at `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for your answer. I am interested, if this a general mathematical convention or Wolfram Mathematica convention to always plot the result on y axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly normal mathematical and scientific convention. The independent variable (i.e., what you put into the expression as defined in the 2nd argument) goes on the horizontal axis and the dependent variable (i.e., what comes out after evaluation of the expression in the 1st argument) goes on the vertical axis. This is not a convention specific to Mathematica: it's used everywhere.

If you want to swap the axes, use `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{-3*x + 2, x}, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "x"}
]
```

> [image]